# How to open more file in same window on different tag (using quanta plus editor)

Tags: kde

Hello everybody
I'm facing a problem with quanta plus when I open more than one file in quanta plus every file opens in new window of quanta plus instead of in a new tab.
Please reply urgent
Shalu

Answer (score 2):

Go to: System -> Preferences -> Main Menu -> Programming -> Quanta Plus -> Properties -> Command  ... then change `quanta %U` to `quanta --unique %U`

`man quanta` ... OPTIONS

- `--unique`  Run as a one-instance application.

Comment: I followed it in Ubuntu 10.04. But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you do not give a lot information, so I can only make a guess. I would look in the Windows menu under MDI mode. Toplevel and Childframe modes give you multiple windows, IDEAI is probably what you want.

Comment: Sir, I mean, when I double click on a php file then it open in quanta plus, but when I need to open another file and I again double click on that file open in another window of quanta plus. I want, when I open second file it shoud be open in same window in other tab.